# In bittorrent's bep 42, why is the ip masked with 0x030f3fff, before being used to calculate a hash?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

In https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0042.html it states:

> The expression to calculate a valid ID prefix (from an IPv4 address)
> is:
>
> crc32c((ip & 0x030f3fff) | (r << 29)) And for an IPv6 address (ip is
> the high 64 bits of the address):
>
> crc32c((ip & 0x0103070f1f3f7fff) | (r << 61))
>
> r is a random number in
> the range [0, 7]. The resulting integer, representing the masked IP
> address is supposed to be big-endian before hashed. The "|" operator
> means bit-wise OR.

Why is ip4 and ip6 bitwise and'ed with 0x030f3fff and 0x0103070f1f3f7fff respectively?

Comment: take a look at the octet-wide modulus lines in the charts

Comment: I don't understand what the charts have to do with it, and what they are trying convey at all for that matter. Let's just look at the ip4 chart. It shows that for any number of controlled bits <= 20, then the "octet-wide modulus" (which I assume refers to their algorithm), allows control of more ip's than just a hash of ip (>20 bits is a ludicrous number of bits for a typical attacker to control). What else are the charts showing besides that?

Comment: They show that the relationship is not linear. that's part of what the mask accomplishes

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something. What is the purpose of making it not linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask introduces a non-linear relationship between which octet one has control over vs. the number of distinct node ID prefixes one can generate.

I think the model here is that if you acquire address-blocks, say 8 /24 prefixes then that gives you 2048 addresses. But whether those addresses are within the same /8 block or spread over many blocks doesn't make as much of a difference, in the end you still control the same number of addresses. So you get 8 bits of entropy from it being /24-chunked and then 3 additional bits to uniquely distinguish those prefixes, not a full 3 bytes.